# Android - MediaPlayer will not release when called from another class

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have a RecyclerView in which I add elements and can click them to play a sound. If I create all the MediaPlayer methods inside the Adapter class everything will be properly released and only one audio will be played at a time.

```
//this works (code in the adapter class)
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

//release if not playing
public void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    // if no sound is playing
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        Log.d("rEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE", "releaseMediaPlayer: ");
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
}

//release media player on sound finish
public MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        releaseMediaPlayer();
    }
};
// on click listener code
releaseMediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, word.getmAudioResourceId());
mMediaPlayer.start();
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
```

However if I use a separate class, whenever i call the the release method it doesn't release at the beginning so multiple sounds are being played at once. It releases normally onCompletion

```
public class MediaPlay {
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

public void setmMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer) {
    this.mMediaPlayer = mMediaPlayer;
}

public MediaPlayer getmMediaPlayer() {
    return mMediaPlayer;
}

//release if not playing
public void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    // if no sound is playing
   if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        Log.d("rEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE", "releaseMediaPlayer: ");
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
}

//release media player on sound finish
public MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        releaseMediaPlayer();
    }
};
```

}

onclicklistener when using class

```
final MediaPlay m = new MediaPlay();
m.releaseMediaPlayer(); 
m.setmMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer.create(context, word.getmAudioResourceId()));
m.getmMediaPlayer().start();
m.getmMediaPlayer().setOnCompletionListener(m.mCompletionListener);
```

I have tried creating the MediaPlay object outside the clickListener but with no result. I am basically trying to create a separate class so i can call it from my ACtivities so I can stop the sound int the onStop method.
Any input will be much appreciated.

edit 1 entire viewholder with click listener

```
    MediaPlay m;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        //play specific sound for each list item
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("ViewHolder: ", String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()));
                Word word = Words.get(getAdapterPosition());
                if (word.hasAudio()) {

                    /*releaseMediaPlayer(); // stop multiple playbacks at once
                    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, word.getmAudioResourceId());
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener); //cleanup*/

                    if (m != null)
                        m.releaseMediaPlayer();

                    m = new MediaPlay();
                    //m.releaseMediaPlayer(); //TODO still plays duplicate sounds, release method not working when called like this
                    m.setmMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer.create(context, word.getmAudioResourceId()));
                    m.getmMediaPlayer().start();
                    m.getmMediaPlayer().setOnCompletionListener(m.mCompletionListener);
                }
            }
        });

        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameT);
        type = itemView.findViewById(R.id.typeT);
        img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgV);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your source code with using a callback.

Please look carefully at the MyViewHolder class and onCreateViewHolder method of MyAdapter :).

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] mDataSet;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView mTextView;
        private OnMediaPlayRequestedListener mOnMediaPlayRequestedListener;

        public MyViewHolder(TextView v, OnMediaPlayRequestedListener listener) {
            super(v);

            mTextView = v;
            mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mOnMediaPlayRequestedListener != null) {
                        mOnMediaPlayRequestedListener.onMediaPlayRequested(R.raw.{resource name});
                    }
                }
            });

            mOnMediaPlayRequestedListener = listener;
        }

        private interface OnMediaPlayRequestedListener {
            void onMediaPlayRequested(int resourceId);
        }
    }

    public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] myDataset) {
        mContext = context;
        mDataSet = myDataset;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        TextView view =
                (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(
                view,
                new MyViewHolder.OnMediaPlayRequestedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMediaPlayRequested(int resourceId) {
                        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                            mMediaPlayer.stop();
                            mMediaPlayer.release();
                        }

                        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, resourceId);
                        mMediaPlayer.start();
                        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                mediaPlayer.release();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });


        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        viewHolder.mTextView.setText(mDataSet[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataSet.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried modifying my code to what you suggested, but sadly It didn't work. Several audio files are still being played at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your checking. Could you attach more codes how did you set the click listener?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I added my entire viewholder where I create the click listenter. The block of code which  is commented out works right (it stopts the previous audio on a new click and stops the current one).

Comment: Hello @Jinzo, I modified answer. Could you check and try it?

Comment: Hello thanks for taking the time to put this together, but what I wanted is a separate class the the mediaplayer functions are stored. As I tried to explain in my question i already have working version in which everything is stored inside the adapter, i want to have everything mediaplayer related in another class and be able to call it from anywhere in my program.

Comment: I managed to solve everything by adding mMedialayer.stop() , like you suggested, to my releaseMediaPlayer() function stored in the MediaPlay class and make both the whole method and the mMediaPlay variable inside the class static. Now i call the release function directly by importing the class instead of over an object.